# An 'easy' way to capture video

Tags: vb.net, winforms, video, webcam

I've been trying to play with DirectShow but it's getting on top of me and my question on here didn't answered so I'm thinking maybe I should go with a different approach. ([DirectShow VB.net can't change recording format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143161/directshow-vb-net-cant-change-recording-format)). <- Where as that 'works' I can't get it in the format I want it, and I don't really understand it so I'd obviousl like to go down the route of something I can get my head around.

I've googled till my fingers are raw trying to come up with an easy way to record video in my vb.net application, it doesn't have to be fancy, just a preview with a start record, stop record button, that's it.

Any pushes in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: You may want to try researching the [avicap32.dll](http://www.bing.com/search?q=avicap32.dll+tutorial&qs=AS&form=QBRE&pq=avicap32.dll+&sc=8-13&sp=8&sk=HS1AS6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library) project. Thanks to the CLR anything in C# is available in VB.NET also.

[image: WinForms Webcam]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample project on MSDN for capturing video data using VB.NET: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-To-Create-Webcam-bbdcc90f

The idea is to use the avicap32.dll to fetch as an external system call.